# How to paginate data from two separate tables with identical structure?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm writing an API in Laravel, where I'm trying to return filtered and/or sorted data from two tables `incoming` and `outgoing`. They have the same structure. I'm not able to modify these tables in any way.

I've currently got this running against one of the tables, using Laravels built in pagination etc.

My problem comes when adding the other table. What I want to do:

- Somehow run a eloquent query against two tables at the same time, letting me use the standard pagination on the result.

What it seems I have to do:

- Do two queries, merge and sort the combined results, and then figure out pagination of the new results.

Is there a good, non-hacky, way of doing this?

Comment: just thoughts. Create a view that is the union of the two tables?  add an indicator column in theview and use that in in you code?

Comment: @RyanVincent Ah, that's probably a good idea! I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Boivie did the idea with a view worked for you?

Comment: @DmitryShvetsov I don't think I ever got it working, ended up creating a merged table instead.

Comment: @Boivie I never heard about the term "merged table". What is it?

Comment: @DmitryShvetsov Oh it's not really a term, we just created a new table with the same structure and one additional column to indicate incoming/outgoing. Then we moved the data from the two original tables into the new table, and can now query that table to access all the data.

Comment: @Boivie I see. Thank you for the explanation!